# Where is this solitary building with a town and mountains in the background behind a valley?

Tags: identify-this, architecture

This is an image from the LG TV screen saver. Does anyone have any idea where this place is?

[image]

Comment: If I lived there I'd never get any work done.

Comment: @puppetsock: It really is a beautiful city, even without the photoshop saturation slider at 11. As a bonus, there's a huge [aqueduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqueduct_of_Segovia) on the other side of town.  It's built with unmortared, brick-like granite blocks and has been standing for more than 2 millenias.

Answer (score 31):

I've never seen this place myself, nor heard about it before today, but after some research online, I'm fairly certain this is [Segovia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segovia) in Spain.

[image: View of Segovia]

Above is a picture of the same city from a slightly different angle. (Image credit [Carlos Delgado](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Kadellar), Original at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Segovia_-_01.jpg))

The big church in the middle is the [Segovia cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segovia_Cathedral) . The small church in the foreground of your picture is the [Iglesia de la Vera Cruz](http://Iglesia_de_la_Vera_Cruz_(Segovia)).

[image: Iglesia de la Vera Cruz]

(Image credit [Ziegler175](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Ziegler175), Original at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SegoviaIglesiaVeraCruz.jpg))

The town is a UNESCO world heritage site.

The mountains at the back are the [Sierra de Guadarrama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_de_Guadarrama).

Comment: Just curious, how did you find out it's Segovia?

Comment: Searched for 'cathedral mountains'. I'm amazed myself that actually worked.

Answer (score 15):

It's a view of the façade of the Segovia Cathedral, the ancient City Walls (8th century), and the Guadarrama mountains.

[image]

[image]